# Unable to read Json File using a MockServerResponse

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, retrofit, mockwebserver

I have been working with `Retrofit` and I am trying to Unit test the code. So I tried to create a mock Json file called `success_response.json` and `failed_response.json` and saved it inside a resource folder in my project. When I test below code, it throws `NullPointerException`

```
@Test
fun `read Sample Success Json File `() {
   val reader = MockResponseFileReader("success_response.json")
   assertNotNull(reader.content)
}
```

**MockResponseFileReader.kt**

```kotlin
class MockResponseFileReader(path : String) {

 var content : String

 init {
     val reader = InputStreamReader(this.javaClass.classLoader?.getResourceAsStream(path))
     content = reader.readText()
     reader.close()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add some checks around your `InputStream`. I'm using this:

```kotlin
internal fun getStringFromFile(filePath: String, debug: Boolean = false): String {
    val classLoader = NetworkTestHelper::class.java.classLoader
    if (classLoader != null) {
        try {
            val inputString = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filePath).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
            if (debug) println("Output from inputfile is: $inputString")
            return inputString
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            println("Could not find the specified file: $filePath")
            throw e
        }
    } else {
        throw IllegalStateException(
            """Classloader is null. Can't open an inputstream for the specified file: $filePath without it."""
        )
    }
}
```

The above builds on the following project structure:

[image]

Add this to you `build.gradle`(App) file if you want your files to be accessible from both unit and instrumentation tests:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        def commonTestDir = 'src/commonTest/java'
        test {
            java.srcDirs += commonTestDir
            resources.srcDirs += ['src/commonTest/resources']
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs += commonTestDir
            resources.srcDirs += ['src/commonTest/resources']
        }
    }
    ...
```

And you use it like this in tests:

```kotlin
@Test
fun whenClickingOk_shouldSaveSelectedItems() {
    mockWebServer.enqueue(
        MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(200)
            .setBody(
                getStringFromFile(
                    "worklist/multiple_worklist_item_result.json",
                    true
                )
            )
    )
    ... // Rest of your test code
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the file is not being read from the Assets Folder. Because of that it throws NullPointerException. This is my path "src/main/assets/success_response.json". And also I have tired passing "success_response.json" too. Still the same issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Plz accept my answer if it worked.